# MySQL won't start out of the blue (using wamp)

Tags: mysql, wamp

I installed WAMP (package of apache, php, mysql and phpMyAdmin) to make some local development and everything has been working fine for a week. Out of the blue mysql don't want to start.

I searched the error from the log and people are talking about file permission but it does not even seem to exist, I can't find it at all. Now my worries are how to fix my issue and how to make sure it does not reproduce itself again.

Here is the error log I am talking about with:

```
...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 10838691
2015-11-02 02:56:21 1352 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-02 02:56:21 1352 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-02 02:56:21 1352 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 10838691
2015-11-02 02:56:21 1352 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-11-02 02:56:21 1352 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-11-02 02:56:21 1352 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-11-02 02:56:21 1352 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-11-02 02:56:21 1352 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: La table 'mysql.user' n'existe pas
```

Here I will leave also the [my.ini](http://pastebin.com/ENR2AC9e) (mysql config file)

Help will be really appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:
Oh yes I forgot to mention that I am on windows 8.1

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/295613/192658

Comment: Quite simply you have somehow deleted one or more files from `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\data\mysql` These are part of the database MYSQL uses to manage itself and the databases and tables and user permission etc etc you create.

Comment: I do understand that the files got somehow deletes but I do not touch my directories directly. How did that happen in the first place?